# Is it safe for std::generate_n's functor to capture and operate on container it's used for populating?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Lately I've been playing with STL algorithms and lambdas to achieve not-so-trivial functionality. Couple of weeks ago I've been told that it's illegal for a predicate (for exmaple - a lambda used in `std::count_if`) to modify value passed to it.

I just accepted that and remembered to never try to do anything like that. However, I've just encountered a potentially similar situation, and I am not sure whether it's *legal* to use code like this:

```
auto generate_n_fib(const std::size_t count = 2) {
    assert(count != 0);
    if(count == 1) {
        return std::vector<std::size_t>{0};
    }
    if(count == 2) {
        return std::vector<std::size_t>{0, 1};
    }
    std::vector<std::size_t> fib{};
    fib.emplace_back(0);
    fib.emplace_back(1);

    if(count > 2) {
        std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(fib), count - 2, [&fib](){
            const auto last = fib.size() - 1;
            return fib[last] + fib[last - 1];
        });
    }

    return fib;
}
```

As you can see, the function above generates the first `count` numbers from Fibonacci sequence. The relevant part is the `std::generate_n` call.

My question is - is it safe for a *generator function* to access fields of a collection that is modified by an algorithm that uses that very *generator function*?

Comment: The last paragraph in this question asks about generator functions ***in general***, and not about ***this*** specific generator function. The shown generator function is well-formed. But it's not too hard to think of a counter-example involving a generator function that captures its container, and then does something in a manner that results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik that's a very good point. Perhaps I should've split the question into generator functions that only `const`-access and non-`const`-access the container.

Comment: `const`-ness is not necessarily the driving factor. If, say, the generator captures `vec.begin()` by value, and does nothing more than dereference it, it can still be undefined behavior. Given that this generator effectively `push_back()`, it invalidates all existing iterators, so using the captured `begin()` iterator will be undefined behavior. But doing the same thing with a vector that's `resize()`d in advance, and a simple forward iterator through the existing contents of the vector, capturing `begin()` and dereferencing it will be perfectly fine.

Comment: Although this method is valid as others answered, I think it's important to point out that it's not necessarily the best way of implementing a Fibonacci generator using `generate_n`. For example, adding captured variables to store the last two values instead of reading from the vector removes any assumptions about how generate_n is specified to work (therefore making the code easier to understand for those less familiar with the language), and could make it more efficient as vector element access is no longer required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible implementation of [`std::generate_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) is:

```
template< class OutputIt, class Size, class Generator >
OutputIt generate_n( OutputIt first, Size count, Generator g )
{
    for( Size i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
        *first++ = g(); 
    }
    return first;
}
```

The expression `*first++` in the *for-loop* is the equivalent as calling `push_back` in the original vector `fib`. If you replace that expression  by what it does, the *for-loop* is pretty much equivalent to:

```
for( Size i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
    fib.push_back(g());
}
```

being `g` the named lambda:

```
auto g = [&fib]() {
    const auto last = fib.size() - 1;
    return fib[last] + fib[last - 1];
};
```

and that's well defined.

We can still unwrap the operations; get rid of the lambda, the back inserter iterator and do all the job in the *for-loop* and yet have a well-defined code.

Comment: This is only one **possible** implementation.

Comment: @Rakete1111 What if an implementation first stores all the generated values, then assigns them all together?

Comment: @Why? Which rule does this implementation violate?

Comment: @xskxzr Oops, seems like you're right. Doesn't seem to violate http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms#alg.generate-3